# Confidence value for libtiff

Tags: libtiff, libtiff.net

Other tools such as Tesseract return a confidence value for read text.  Does Bit Miracle - libtiff offer this confidence value?

Would like to be able to test document for readability - for example not blurred.

Comment: Does libtff projecet have an online documentation?